# POST request using alamofire 2.0 and Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

I try to create a basic function that send a POST request using Alamofire.

```
@IBAction func createBasicAccount(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var firstNameToSend = firstName.text
    var lastNameToSend = lastName.text
    var mailAddressToSend = mailAddress.text
    var passwordToSend = password.text
    var parametersToSend = [
        "firstName": firstNameToSend,
        "lastName": lastNameToSend,
        "mailAddress": mailAddressToSend,
        "password": passwordToSend
    ]

    print("Account creation")

    Alamofire.request(.POST, postEndpoint, parameters: parametersToSend, encoding: .JSON)
}
```

But the `Alamofire.request` won't compile and compiler returns:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : String?]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
```

I tried:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, postEndpoint, parameters: parametersToSend as! AnyObject as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)
```

But fails:

```
Account creation
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.Optional<Swift.String>>' (0x11fdb1038) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x12035b018).
```

I'm using *Swift 2.0*, *Xcode 7.0 GM Seed*, *iOS 8.4* & *Alamofire 2.0*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that's a optional type problem. Can you try to add ! to your variables such as:

```
var parametersToSend = [
        "firstName": firstNameToSend!,
        "lastName": lastNameToSend!,
        "mailAddress": mailAddressToSend!,
        "password": passwordToSend!
    ]
```

Comment: I'm so dumb ... Thank you so much !

Comment: Thanks a lot you save my time. @VivienG same here :(.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS LATEST VERIOSN CODE OF SWIFT 2.2 HOPE ITS HELOP YOU....
This is latest answer of SWIFT 2.2 VERSION

try this one its helps you....

PARAMETERS:-

```
    let params : Dictionary = ["YourKEY" : "YourVALUE"]
```

Post Request_Form:-

```
Alamofire.request(.POST,"Post Your Url HERE", parameters: params, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON
        {
          response in switch response.result 
            {
                  case .Success(let JSON):
         //   print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
            //converting json into NSDictionary

            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
            print(response)

            var array = NSMutableArray!()
            //converting respose form into NSMutableArray formate
            array = response.valueForKey("countryList")as? NSMutableArray

            //example if there is an id
          //  let userId = response.objectForKey("id")!

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
```